# Java differentiate between serialization on disk over network

Tags: java, networking, serialization

I am trying to serialize my simple POJO object over the disk and over the network as well. But i need to control the attributes which can be serialized.
For example:

```
class POJO
{
    String name;
    int age;
}
```

Now in this above example i want the name and age both to be serialized on disk. But i only want age to be serialized over the network. 
After doing some R&D , i have found two ways to do that but i haven't been able to develop a good full functional solution yet.

**Solution 1**: Use transient keyword.

**Problem**: If i use transient it stops the serialization at all.

**Solution 2**: Make use of externalizable interface.

**Problem**: If i use this interface, i have to implement two methods and control serialization my self. How would i know that this time my method is being called for serialization on disk or over network. And if somehow i do figure out this by use of some flag, then the code would be messy.

**My Idea** is some form of design level solution . Such as to create an interface that exposes getters methods for only those properties which needs to be serialized. Then using that, i can read and write object, and java upon deserilization automatically detects through reflection or something that i have to serialize/deserialize only those attributs for which getter method is exposed.
**Does java have something like this?**

**Or** perhaps something more cleaner, elegant, and neater solution for that.

Please help me out in this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[Use customized serializes.](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/javaserial-1536170.html) One for disk, and other one for network.